# Как сравнить число с элементами в списке?

Tags: python, алгоритм

У меня есть следующий код:

```
number_1 = 1234 #Например

list_number = [0, 10, 20, 30, 
            50, 55, 89, 150, 160, 
            170, 180, 200, 220, 260, 
            320, 340, 385, 420, 367,
            545, 578, 600, 605, 740,
            750, 844, 850, 940, 950,
            1000, 1052, 1106, 1150, 1200,
            1270, 1300, 1358, 1408, 1460,]
```

Я хочу, чтобы мне вывелся 1 элемент из упорядоченного списка, который будет меньше этого числа:
Если `number_1 = 1234`, то будет 1200 и на вывод 33 элемент

Да, здесь можно циклом пройтись, но как быть, если у меня будет много элементов в списке?
Может, какой-нибудь модуль есть?

Comment: а почему не 0, это ведь тоже слева от 1234

Comment: Мне нужен только 1 элемент, который будет меньше сразу перед ним

Comment: вам список чисел `list_number` всегда отсортирован в порядке возрастания ?

Comment: Да, всегда в порядке возрастания

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Да, здесь можно циклом пройтись, но как быть, если у меня будет много элементов в списке? Может, какой-нибудь модуль есть?

Модули в любом случае будут использовать циклы (*просто скрывая их от вас*).

---

Т.к. вы в комментариях вы указали, что список **всегда будет отсортирован** можно использовать немного модифицированный [бинарный поиск](https://pythonpip.ru/examples/dvoichnyy-poisk-python) для уменьшения кол-ва итераций.

Comment: Вмесо самописных алгоритмов можно использовать библиотечный модуль `bisect`

Comment: вы ответили на мой вопрос я вот хочу узнать вы бы могли мне рассказать как это сделать?

Comment: @ВалерийКнязев а что именно вам непонятно?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ:

```
i = -1
while i<len(list_number)-1:
    if list_number[i+1] >= number_1:
        break
    i += 1
print(list_number[i])
```

В Python 3.10 можно написать так:

```
i = -1
while (i:=i+1) < len(list_number)-1:
    if list_number[i+1] >= number_1:
        break 
print(list_number[i])
```

Есть еще такой способ, но его я бы не стал рекомендовать из-за долгого выполнения на больших объемах данных:

```
print(max(filter(lambda x: x<number_1, list_number)))
```